# The ngrams sentence challenge

Tags: optimization, google-ngram

When you enter a search into [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams), the graph shows the words/strings down the right hand side. What if you could pick search terms such that reading the right hand side of the graph, from top to bottom, makes an actual sentence...

**Challenge**

What is the longest sentence you can create in google ngrams by reading the search terms down the right hand side of the graph?

**Example**

A nice simple one to start you off. I give you, for a score of 4:

> [This sentence scores poorly.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=This%2Csentence%2Cscores%2Cpoorly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csentence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscores%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoorly%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [image: Graph for "This sentence scores poorly."]

**Rules**

1. Each word must be its own ngrams search term (no strings as search terms)
2. The sentence must be in English. You must use the corpus "English".
3. The sentence must make grammatical sense. To achieve this, you are allowed to insert punctuation in your sentence which is not present in your ngrams search.
4. You are not allowed to tick "case insensitive". (Because it spoils the look by adding *(All)* to the end of each word). Capitals are allowed where they make grammatical sense (beginning of sentence, proper nouns) but are not required.
5. You may not string endless adjectives or adverbs together; only one adjective to describe each object and one adverb to describe each verb, *unless you can put a joining word in between*. i.e. "The big red awesome car" would not be acceptable, but "the awesome car which was big and red" would be... although clearly that example isn't going to appear in order! Note that possessive nouns (e.g. "my *sister's* car") are adjectives and hence fall under this rule.
6. You are allowed to change the end year of your search from the default.
7. The maximum score possible is 12, because google ngrams only allows 12 search terms.

Comment: If anyone could tell me the steps to embed a screengrab of my example graph as a picture, I'd be very grateful. Presumably I need to take a screengrab, save it to my PC, then upload it to somewhere?

Comment: I cannot understand your question. What do you mean by *the longest sentence* possible? I could enter any sentence that I choose..

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - no, try "this is a really long sentence that does not work" I get, from top to bottom down the right, ["a is that not this work does long really sentence"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%2Cis%2Ca%2Creally%2Clong%2Csentence%2Cthat%2Cdoes%2C+not%2Cwork&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csentence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @AndyT. To embed an image, save a screengrab to your PC, then edit your question and click on the icon with a mountain on it to insert an image.

Comment: Is there a limit of 12 words for ngrams - if so this makes the puzzle a bit less interesting?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the start year as well?

Comment: @Miff - It would appear so. I wasn't aware of that. I think it'd be difficult to get that high though.

Comment: @EngineerToast - You could change the start year... I'm not sure that'd help though. The words on the right hand side are ordered by the end year; the start year has no effect on that.

Comment: @AndyT I didn't like how big the graph was so I used the link to embed it elsewhere, changed the size there, took a screenshot saved as PNG, and then inserted it here. StackExchange sites let you upload images directly in the editor and it stores them on Imgur and links to them for you.

Comment: This is easy to exploit, like by listing color adjectives in order of frequency. All such puzzles are won by whoever stretches the meaning of sentence most.  Asking to make sentences with a given property simply does not work as a puzzle.

Comment: @xnor - You'll notice I excluded strings of adjectives. I did think about this a bit and *try* to close out exploitations.

Comment: @AndyT My mistake, I should have read more carefully. Still, despite your efforts, I think it's impractical to close out all the loopholes on challenges like this.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes the words appear out of order on the right-hand-side compared to the numbers reported by hovering over the graph. (Usually they're very close.) Is the metric solely the presentation of the words themselves to the right of the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

13:  Just modifying a previous answer yields higher results:
[A,new,man,through,life,without,true,love,today,normally,allows,medicinal,marijuana](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A%2Cnew%2Cman%2Cthrough%2Clife%2Cwithout%2Ctrue%2Clove%2Ctoday%2Cnormally%2Callows%2Cmedicinal&year_start=1800&year_end=1972&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clove%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnormally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Callows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedicinal%3B%2Cc0)
 (Though I will point out that google stops showing them after 12.  So the answer may just be 12.

Comment: Yep, maximum is 12. I've now added this as rule no7 (although it's more of a clarification of google ngrams limitations than a rule I'm "imposing").

Comment: As the first answer to reach 12, that I judge to have met the rules, I have accepted this answer. Well done geniusadam!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a particularly dark **12-point**er:

> [The very good man—though usually kind—considered killing babies marginally unconscionable.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%2Cvery%2Cgood%2Cman%2Cthough%2Ckind%2Cusually%2Cconsidered%2Ckilling%2Cbabies%2Cmarginally%2Cunconscionable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckilling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbabies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarginally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunconscionable%3B%2Cc0)

Here's a screenshot of the hover window for the year 2000:

[image]

Comment: +1. Though it turns out the word order on the hover window... is actually just the search order. Gah. Looks like I have to manually check the correct order for entries.

Comment: Oh wow, haha, I never noticed that. I updated my answer to have them in the correct order.

Answer (score 3):

### 10 points

A somewhat morbid sentence, perhaps from a proponent of eugenics:

*[A new man without true love requires severe anesthesia perfunctorily](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A%2Cnew%2Cman%2Cwithout%2Ctrue%2Clove%2Crequires%2Csevere%2Canesthesia%2Cperfunctorily&year_start=1800&year_end=1975&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)*

(Note that this uses an end year of 1975.  After that point, ***love*** overtakes ***true***.)

Comment: I'm getting "perfunctorily anesthesia" rather than "anesthesia perfunctorily"... Perhaps spelling anaesthesia correctly might help?

Comment: @AndyT I think all of `anesthesia` (American spelling), `anaesthesia` (British spelling), and `perfunctorily` have [0 results (or close enough that it gets rounded to 0](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anaesthesia%2Canesthesia%2Cperfunctorily&year_start=1800&year_end=1975&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&).  It appears that ngrams orders results with the same value randomly.  When I spelled it with the extra `a`, it appeared in the wrong order for me, which is why I chose the American spelling.  It appears it isn't consistent for everyone, though.

Comment: And today when I click on your same, unedited, link, it puts them in the right order! Google ngrams seems determined to destroy my challenge!

Answer (score 3):

## 12 points

> "This could very much run counter vs. prevailing ideologies," quoth Slavoj Zizek.

[image]

Comment: Good effort. But "run counter vs" falls foul of rule no 3 - in my view it is not grammatical.

Comment: Agreed. 'run counter to' would work but not  'vs'.

Comment: It does have some results in Google Books, but I agree it's at least bad writing. I'd argue it's still grammatical, just redundant (versus and to are the same part of speech, so they should be interchangeable syntactically).

Comment: @histocrat - I haven't found any results in google books for [run counter vs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+counter+vs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pHbvMbMZKjQC&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq="run+counter+versus"

Comment: @histocrat - looking into that particular quote (which appears to be the only one in google books) I *think* it means "run *a counter play* against fast flowing defenses".

Answer (score 2):

[Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0) trivially scores 8.

[Explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: Actually, this does not work. If you properly capitalize it (three of those buffalos are the name of a city), it shows the capital Buffalos first in the right-hand list. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Buffalo%2Cbuffalo%2CBuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2Cbuffalo%2CBuffalo%2Cbuffalo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBuffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffalo%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @IanMacDonald I was relying on my reading of rule 4 saying that capitals were not required

Comment: Add the words "some, poor" for a score of 10: *some poor Buffalo ...*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another **12-pointer** that I believe satisfies all the rules. Unfortunately, for some reason Google does not place the words in the correct order on the right-hand side, but at all points within the selected date range the order of the word frequency (when you hover over the graph) is in the correct sentence order.

[I just love quickly finding perfect answers (comments aside) - resolving puzzles cleverly.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%2Cjust%2Clove%2Cquickly%2Cfinding%2Cperfect%2Canswers%2Ccomments%2Caside%2Cresolving%2Cpuzzles%2Ccleverly&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clove%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquickly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperfect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canswers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caside%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresolving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpuzzles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccleverly%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one for 12 points:

> [I would very much want dead horse ears atop James's chariot archer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%2Cwould%2Cvery%2Cmuch%2Cwant%2Cdead%2Chorse%2Cears%2Catop%2CJames%27s%2Cchariot%2Carcher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chorse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cears%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CJames%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchariot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carcher%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm afraid that gives an order of: *I would very much want dead horse **atop chariot hooves archer alexander 's***, based on your link.

Comment: Also, it turns out [a possessive noun is an adjective](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=is%20a%20possessive%20noun%20an%20adjective). Therefore "alexander's chariot archer" would not be allowed as both "alexander's" and "chariot" are adjectives of archer.

Comment: @AndyT I understand your first comment, but to the second one, I'm not sure you can consider "chariot" an adjective. It's not as if you could say "that archer is chariot".

Comment: Also, changed it to fix the ordering of the last words

Comment: Then, out of interest, what do you think "James's chariot archer" means? I believe it means an archer, who is riding a chariot, who belongs to James. If so, "chariot" is an adjective.

Comment: That is what it means, but "chariot archer" is a compound noun made of two nouns. See http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/compound-nouns/